# Adding Requesttypes to JIRA Issue via API

Tags: python, api, rest, jira

I'm currently trying to add a requesttype to a JIRA issue via REST API. I know the id of the requesttype.
For accessing the API I'm using the jira Package, installed via pip.

```
issue = jirasession.create_issue(project=jiraProject, summary="My Summary", description = description, issuetype = {'name' : 'Issuetype'},\
                                 priority = {'name' : 'Intermediate'}, customfield_12444={'value':'...'}, reporter = {"name": '...'}, \
                                 duedate = '...')
```

I tried things like adding this field but it fails:

`customfield_11240 = {'requestType':{'name': 'my requesttype'}})`

customfield_11240 is the field where the RequestType is stored, when I access the Ticket via API (issue = jira.issue("myre-2299"))

`'customfield_11240': {'_links': {'jiraRest': 'http://MyDomain/jira/rest/api/2/issue/521700', 'web': 'http://MyDomain/jira/servicedesk/customer/portal/35/MYRE-2299', 'self': 'http://MyDomain/jira/rest/servicedeskapi/request/521700'}, 'requestType': {'id': '472', '_links': {'self': 'http://MyDomain/jira/rest/servicedeskapi/servicedesk/35/requesttype/472'}...'`

I cannot find a proper solution in the docs for this.

Thanks in advance!